# WebRTC is disconnected by server on LTE network only but a wifi and 5g networks are ok

Tags: android, networking, webrtc

I am developing a project for streaming service based on WebRTC.

It's working on android app when it uses wifi network and 5G network.
But, It does not work based on LTE network.

I've tried many STUN and TURN server instead of stun:stun.l.google.com.

This is the capture of network log.
Please give me any advice.

**5G => Working**

```
NetworkMonitorAutoDetect: capabilities changed: [ Transports: CELLULAR Capabilities: SUPL&INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN&VALIDATED&NOT_ROAMING&FOREGROUND&NOT_CONGESTED&NOT_SUSPENDED LinkUpBandwidth>=15000Kbps LinkDnBandwidth>=47000Kbps Specifier: <1>]
NetworkMonitorAutoDetect: link properties changed: {InterfaceName: rmnet_data1 LinkAddresses: [ 192.0.0.2/27,2001:2d8:e712:c6b5:4c89:79ae:bd68:63b6/64 ] DnsAddresses: [ /192.0.0.1,/fd00:613:101:c::10,/fd00:e13:101:c::7 ] Domains: null MTU: 1440 TcpBufferSizes: 2097152,6291456,16777216,512000,2097152,8388608 Routes: [ 0.0.0.0/0 -> 192.0.0.1 rmnet_data1,::/0 -> fe80::3 rmnet_data1,192.0.0.0/27 -> 0.0.0.0 rmnet_data1,2001:2d8:e712:c6b5::/64 -> :: rmnet_data1 ]}
```

**Wifi => Working**

```
NetworkMonitorAutoDetect: capabilities changed: [ Transports: WIFI Capabilities: NOT_METERED&INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN&VALIDATED&NOT_ROAMING&FOREGROUND&NOT_CONGESTED&NOT_SUSPENDED Unwanted:  LinkUpBandwidth>=1048576Kbps LinkDnBandwidth>=1048576Kbps SignalStrength: -47 SSID: "ONEPUNMAN"]
NetworkMonitorAutoDetect: link properties changed: {InterfaceName: wlan0 LinkAddresses: [fe80::5ba5:5505:4450:aa9a/64,192.168.0.5/24,]  Routes: [fe80::/64 -> :: wlan0,192.168.0.0/24 -> 0.0.0.0 wlan0,0.0.0.0/0 -> 192.168.0.1 wlan0,] DnsAddresses: [210.220.163.82,219.250.36.130,] UsePrivateDns: false PrivateDnsServerName: null Domains: null MTU: 0 TcpBufferSizes: 524288,1048576,4194304,524288,1048576,4194304}
```

**LTE => Not Working**

```
NetworkMonitorAutoDetect: capabilities changed: [ Transports: CELLULAR Capabilities: SUPL&INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN&VALIDATED&NOT_ROAMING&FOREGROUND&NOT_CONGESTED&NOT_SUSPENDED Unwanted:  LinkUpBandwidth>=51200Kbps LinkDnBandwidth>=102400Kbps Specifier: <1>]
NetworkMonitorAutoDetect: link properties changed: {InterfaceName: rmnet1 LinkAddresses: [2001:2d8:306:c674::152e:10a4/64,]  Routes: [::/0 -> fe80::3 rmnet1,2001:2d8:306:c674::/64 -> :: rmnet1,] DnsAddresses: [fd00:e13:301:c::7,fd00:613:301:c::10,] UsePrivateDns: false PrivateDnsServerName: null Domains: null MTU: 1440 TcpBufferSizes: 2097152,4194304,8388608,1048576,3145728,4194304 Stacked: [ [{InterfaceName: v4-rmnet1 LinkAddresses: [192.0.0.5/32,]  Routes: [0.0.0.0/0 -> 192.0.0.5 v4-rmnet1,] DnsAddresses: [] UsePrivateDns: false PrivateDnsServerName: null Domains: null MTU: 0} ],] }
```

Comment: Have same problem. Did you find anything?

Comment: @VygintasB Nope. I failed to solve it. Sorry..

Comment: @yahocho Did you find the reason?